# How to get the size of a double pointer array?

Tags: c, sizeof, double-pointer, pointer-to-pointer

How can I get the size of a dynamically allocated array of double pointers? (pointer to pointer datatype)

```
int tokencnt=1;
tokenv=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));

while(tokencnt<11){
 tokenv=(char**)realloc(tokenv,(tokencnt++)*sizeof(char*));
}

printf(*the size of tokenv*);
```

Comment: Record the size yourself and use it later.

Comment: `tokenv` lastly points to `11*sizeof(char*)` bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof` does not work with alloc memory. If you `malloc` stuff you have to keep track of the size. The reason `sizeof` does not work, is because it will just give you the size of the pointer not the memory it points to.